# How to use the result of a thenCompose multiple times in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, future, completable-future

I have a series of `thenCompose` calls, similar to

```
myObject.updateDB(payload)
      .thenCompose(__ -> getUserID(payload.ID()))
      .thenCompose(id -> getProfile(id))
      .thenCompose(userProfile -> updateSomething(userProfile))
      .thenCompose(__ -> notifyUser(id))
      .thenAccept(__ -> doSomething())
      .exceptionally(t -> doSomethingElse());
```

The `getUserID` call returns a `CompletionStage<String>` which I use in the next call for `getProfile`. I need the same `id` again for the `notifyUser` call. How to make it available there? The IDE is showing

> Cannot resolve symbol id.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your current code is that by the time you reach `.thenCompose(__ -> notifyUser(id))`, the variable `id` is not in scope anymore.

A simple solution in this case would be to invoke multiple `thenCompose` directly on the `CompletionStage` returned by `getProfile`:

```
myObject.updateDB(payload)
  .thenCompose(__ -> getUserID(payload.ID()))
  .thenCompose(id -> 
      getProfile(id)
          .thenCompose(userProfile -> updateSomething(userProfile))
          .thenCompose(__ -> notifyUser(id))
  )
  // rest of chain calls
```

Comment: That’s not a simple solution. A simple solution would be turning this over`compose`d chain into a single code block. There is no benefit in expressing this entirely linear sequence in so many stages. By writing it as a single action, all needed values are in scope and also all these unused parameters disappear…

Answer (score 0):

I think, your code becomes simpler, if you don’t insist on using `thenCompose` for every step:

```
myObject.updateDB(payload)
    .thenCompose(__ -> getUserID(payload.ID()))
    .thenAccept(id -> {
        updateSomething(getProfile(id).join());
        notifyUser(id);
    })
    .thenRun(() -> doSomething())
    .exceptionally(t -> doSomethingElse());
```

If having each step effectively sequential is your requirement, you can simply use `join`:

```
myObject.updateDB(payload)
    .thenCompose(__ -> getUserID(payload.ID()))
    .thenAccept(id -> {
        updateSomething(getProfile(id).join()).join();
        notifyUser(id).join();
    })
    .thenRun(() -> doSomething())
    .exceptionally(t -> doSomethingElse());
```

Considering that the whole chain is effectively sequential, you may just write it straight-forward:

```
myObject.updateDB(payload)
    .thenRun(() -> {
        YourUserIDType id = getUserID(payload.ID()).join();
        updateSomething(getProfile(id).join()).join();
        notifyUser(id).join();
        doSomething();
    })
    .exceptionally(t -> doSomethingElse());
```